# Highmaps MapBubble label stacking

Tags: javascript, highmaps

I am parsing multiple occupations for each country in my `dataArray` to my HighMaps Mapbubble. Highmaps treats them as individual points and stacks them together on top of each other on the map. Because of that, only the most recent occupation is visible on the map as all other occupations are stacked behind the latest one.

Is there a way to make all occupations in the country visible?

This is my current Highmaps code:

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
      chart: {
          borderWidth: 1,
          map: 'custom/world'
      },

      title: {
          text: "Where's everybody from?"
      },

      subtitle: {
          text: 'See where your peers are from and what they do'
      },

      legend: {
          enabled: false
      },

      mapNavigation: {
          enabled: true,
          buttonOptions: {
              verticalAlign: 'bottom'
          }
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Countries',
          color: '#E0E0E0',
          enableMouseTracking: false
      }, {
          type: 'mapbubble',
          name: 'Occupation: ',
          joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
          data: dataArray,
          dataLabels: {
            allowOverlap:false,
            enabled: true,
          },
          minSize: 1,
          maxSize: '10%',
          tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.occupation}'
        }
      }]
  });
```

This is an extract from my Firebase JSON export to show which data format I have:

```
[{
  "code" : "PK",
  "occupation" : "computer science ",
  "z" : 1
},
{
  "code" : "PK",
  "occupation" : "another computer science occupation",
  "z" : 1
},
{
  "code" : "US",
  "occupation" : "manager ",
  "z" : 1
},
{
  "code" : "UG",
  "occupation" : "test24",
  "z" : 1
}]
```

Comment: I think the best solution here would be to pre-process your data, grouping and aggregating it, before sending it to the highmaps. That way, you could get a single Bubble on `PK` with `z = 2` and you can put the the discrimination between `computer science` and `another computer science occupation` in the tooltip, for instance.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that too and frankly, this is the only solution I see right now. It's a bit of a mess trying to sort the data from Firebase after you've already received the JSON

Comment: But you won't need sorting, would you? With a simply `for` you could group the data by `code`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ghaLcqd9/  The `rawData` is like your firebase data